# With a SQL function, how do I take a delimited string and return it as HTML elements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have a DataField that consists of:

Red|Blue|Green|Orange|Black

I'd like to create a function that returns this as a single dynamic variable [Colors] and when rendered it looks like this:

```
<li>Red</li>
<li>Blue</li>
<li>Green</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li>Black</li>
```

So I need to generate the li elements, just as they are above, all within SQL.

I've done this the other way around using STUFF, where I can create this when the values are individual items in a table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @xml as xml
DECLARE @string as varchar(100)

SET @string ='Red|Blue|Green|Orange|Black'
SET @xml = cast( ('<li>' + replace( @string, '|' ,'</li><li>') + '</li>') as xml)

SELECT @xml
```

Comment: Giving this a shot... It seems to be only generating LI elements for the first three and dropping the rest. I'm not sure why yet. Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: Actually I forgot to change varchar(100) to MAX instead. My real code is quite a bit longer than the example I posted. This worked well. Thank you very much.